# Perform function after dynamic content is loaded

Tags: jquery, dynamic, event-handling

I have a table that I need to perform a function on. It is on a search results page though, and the content inside the div changes after a search is performed (or another page of results is loaded). Unfortunately, I don't have access to the ajax method that is called to change the data (it is a function used globablly throughout the site and cannot be changed to this page).

What I am trying to do is, each time the $("#search_results) div changes, I want to loop through the result set, remove the onclick events that are defined inline, and use my own onclick function. Here is a sample (this works the first time the page is loaded, but not after an ajax call changes the search results):

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

    $(document).live(function(){
        alert('fired'); 
        $('table.lookup_table tr').each(function(){
            $(this).removeAttr('onclick');      
        });
    });

$('table.lookup_table tr').on('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).removeAttr('onclick');  
        var pacware = $.trim($(':nth-child(1)', $(this)).html());
        var site = $.trim($(':nth-child(2)', $(this)).html());

        window.location = '<?php echo matry::here_to('edit');?>&pacware_code=' + pacware + '&site_id='+site;
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

*Also, I need this to work in IE 8 *

Comment: which part of the html is being replaced by the other code?

Comment: The whole table is being reloaded with the next 50 values that match the search results

Comment: im havin a really tough time following what you are really trying to do here. please clarify and im sure we can help you.

Comment: also, what you mentioned about a global ajax call is not an uncommon thing but does this global call not accept a callback success function? that seems a little ridiculous to expect you as developers to never use a callback from an ajax call.

Comment: I have a table that is loaded via ajax, each time that table is loaded (after a search), I want to run the function for removing the onclick attributes. I then need to bind my new onclick to each tr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this, but it is not the nice way:

```
$('body').on('click', 'table.lookup_table tr', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        //...
        return false;
    });
```

it will check, on each click, if you clicked an element which matches `table.lookup_table tr` and if so, execute the event handler.

Comment: the prevent default won't stop another onclick event though. So I need to loop through and remove all of the onclicks before binding a new onclick

Comment: In that case, try `e.stopPropagation()` additionally to `e.preventDefault`.

Comment: I ended up changing to .live instead of .on. Since my script redirects, it prevents the other from happening anyway (it was just a pain to test).

Comment: .live() is deprecated and removed in jquery 1.9. The correct way to utilize 'live' handlers is using 'on' the way I showed above, attach to a parent and then provide a subselector. You can also simply use `$(document).on(event, selector, callback)` instead of `$(selector).live(event, callback)` see http://api.jquery.com/live/